# How can I heal my prisoners?

Tags: prison-architect

I currently have a medical ward built, with two doctors assigned to it as well as a psychologist. I have completed the *Health and Well Being* grant.

I have many hurt prisoners, but I can't figure out how to get the doctors to heal them. I've tried "searching" the prisoners to send them to the medical ward and I've tried moving them to the ward manually.

How can I heal my prisoners?

**NOTE**: I'm running alpha 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like medical capabilities are fully coded as of yet.  I've seen the guards occasionally drag a prisoner to the medical ward, but it's fairly rare.

The best method I've found to heal your prisoners is to click on one of your doctors, and then right click on the target to heal.  The doctor will pull out a syringe and pursue the target until caught.  Once the target is completely healed, the doctor will wander her way back to the medical ward.

Comment: Yeah the right click worked, didn't think to try that :S thanks!

Comment: I will hunt you down and **heal you with needles.**

Comment: Medical wards are working now; guards will take injured prisoners to the ward to be healed. No need to go chasing prisoners any more :)

Comment: @Tony then by Alpha 20ish (24 as I write this) we have a regression, because it doesn't seem to work (anymore).  Or... it's wonky.  Under some circumstances... well, I've only ever seen unconscious guards being dragged to the ward by other guards.  I see lots and lots of injured prisoners just left in pain.  But then, it's still alpha.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard - It's possible the bug has returned, I'll have to injure some prisoners and see if they get healed :) I have seen injured prisoners in lock down or solitary, perhaps they have to serve their punishment before they are taken to the medical ward? Harsh.

Answer (score 1):

The version I have has occasionally had guards drag prisoners to the medical ward however, if a prisoner is going to be punished (such as solitary or lock down) the guards never bring the prisoner to the ward so its just easier to right-click on the prisoner and send the doctor chasing. |-[===]---